# Multiply 1st element of every sublist by -1?? Common Lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

As part of a larger project I want to be able to multiple every first element of every sublistby -1. I am trying to do it using recursion at the moment like this:

```
(defun negative (secondpoly)
    (let ((t1(car secondpoly))
         (rem(cdr secondpoly)))
        (let ((c1(car t1)))
            (if (not (null (cdr secondpoly)))
                (negative (append (* c1 -1) rem))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

With this input:

```
(pminus '((5 x 2)(100 x 2)))
```

I want to receive this output:

```
(pminus '((-5 x 2)(-100 x 2)))
```

I was wondering if someone could show me a way to do this?

Comment: Isn't clear. Your input is: `'(pminus ((5 x 2)(100 x 2)))` or `'((5 x 2)(100 x 2))`?

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input really is something like: `'(pminus ((5 x 2)(100 x 2)))`

```
(defun negative-first (poly)
  (cons (car poly)
        (mapcar (lambda (el)
                  (cons (- (car el)) (cdr el)))
                (cadr poly))))

CL-USER> (negative-first '(pminus ((5 x 2)(100 x 2))))
(PMINUS (-5 X 2) (-100 X 2))
```

But for me it looks like there is a mistake in explanation, and your input is `'((5 x 2)(100 x 2))` and if so, your function is:

```
(defun negative-first (poly)
  (mapcar (lambda (el)
            (cons (- (car el)) (cdr el)))
          poly))


CL-USER> (negative-first '((5 x 2)(100 x 2)))
((-5 X 2) (-100 X 2))
```

If you need to work with more nested and complex data, you probably should who some examples, this function will work only with one level `((5 x 2) (100 x 2) (40 x 3) .... )`.